# How can I fit a head rest to an ordinary office high back chair?

Tags: joinery

[image]I find I get a sore back when I lean back, so I need a head rest. However I don't want to buy a new chair and bring it to the office.

How can I fit a head rest to an ordinary office high back chair?

Comment: This is vague (what is the exact style and construction of the chair) and probably off topic (we don't really do furniture). You might try elaborating and possibly post a picture.

Comment: @bib added photo!

Comment: The sore back might not be from the lack of a headrest, but from lack of lumbar support.  Have you tried a throw pillow at the small of your back and see if that changes things?

Comment: I want a head rest to I can lean back on the chair and take less vertical pressure off my back